# Harris score computation in ORB descriptor

Tags: performance, opencv, orb

I was looking into the ORB feature detector code,I understood how FAST is working,but after getting the keypoints to filter good keypoint ORB developers suggested to use harris score instead of fast. But when we are selecting harris score ,I am unable to see there is any code to calculate harris score from thos corners,instead its selecting keypoint based on the FAST score. AM I right?

Comment: what is needed to compute harris score for a single point location?

Comment: harris score or fast score is being used on the corners detected by fast corner detection to filter out some bad corners. What I meant is though in opencv code it is mentioned that by default harris score is being used to filter out some keypoints,but in actual code i dint see anywhere where harris score is being calculated .